# bash reverse order of comma separated values

Tags: bash

I've got the following list of elements:

```
a, b, c, 1337, d, e
```

I wish I have:

```
e, d, 1337, c, b, a
```

How can I achieve that in bash?

Comment: I updated the answer so it's more robust + explanation of the parts, check for the differences =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with **`awk`**:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'BEGIN{FS=",[ ]*"; OFS=", "}
    {
        for (i=NF; i>0; i--) {
            printf "%s", $i;
            if (i>1) {
                printf "%s", OFS;
            }
        }
        printf "\n"
    }'
```

**Explanation** of the script:

- `FS=",[ ]*";`: The regex for *Field Separator* (delimiter for your input) matches a comma followed by zero or more spaces, so your input can be any of:

  - `a, b, c, 1337, d, e`
  - `a,b,c,1337,d,e`
  - `a,  (many spaces)   b, c,1337,d,     e`
- `OFS=", "`: The *Output Field Separator* (delimiter for your output) will be explicitly a comma followed by a space (so output looks consistent)
- `for (i=NF; i>0; i--) { ... }`: `NF` means the *Number of Fields* in the current line. Here we iterate backwards, printing from the last field to the first field.
- `if (i>1) { ... }`: Only print the `OFS` if it's not the last field in the output
- `printf "\n"`: new line.

**Sample usage**:

```
$ ./script_name < input_file > output_file
```

Answer (score 2):

If your input is simple, and the number of columns is static, you could always go with a hardcoded `awk` solution:

```
awk -F, '{ print $6", "$5", "$4", "$3", "$2", "$1 }'
```

This assumes that you have 6 columns that are separated by a comma. If you have a "comma + space" delimiter, `,`, you can use `-F', '` instead of just `-F,`.

A straightforward example usage with output:

```
$ echo "a, b, c, 1337, d, e" | awk -F', ' '{ print $6", "$5", "$4", "$3", "$2", "$1 }'
e, d, 1337, c, b, a
```

With a file as input:

```
awk -F', ' '{ print $6", "$5", "$4", "$3", "$2", "$1 }' your_file
```

You can then redirect the output from that to another file by appending `> reversed_columns`; "reversed_columns" being the name of the new file in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is not very elegant, but should work with any number of fields:

```
sed 's/, /\n/g' | tac | sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\n/, /g'
```

Either pipe you data to it or give a file as second argument to first `sed` (it will print the whole file as one comma-separated line, though).

Comment: FWIW, it would have been possible to do more of it with `tac`: `printf "%s, " "$elts" | tac -s", " | head -c${#elts}`

Comment: @rici Nice! I'd overlooked the `-s` option of `tac`. And I really should get used to using `printf`...

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F", " '{for (i=NF;i;i--) printf "%s ",$i; print ""}' < datafile
e d 1337 c b a
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for to reverse the elements on a line in vim. Great one liner

Answer (score 1):

With the following script, it doesn't matter how many elements are in the list:

```
IFS=', '; read -a array <<< "a, b, c, 1337, d, e"
let i=${#array[@]}-1; 
while [ $i -ge 0 ]; do 
    echo -n "${array[$i]}, "; 
    let i--; 
done
```

Also, you can use the following perl one-liner (it will add a `\n` after the first element though)

```
echo "a, b, c, 1337, d, e" | perl -ne 'foreach(reverse(split(", ",$_))){print "$_, "}'
```

Comment: For your perl, use `-l` to "auto-chomp": `perl -lpe '$_ = join ", ", reverse split /, /'`

Answer (score 1):

bash:

```
echo "a, b, c, 1337, d, e" | (
  IFS=", "
  while read line; do
    set -- $line
    for (( i=$#; i > 1; i-- )); do
      printf "%s, " "${!i}"
    done
    echo "$1"
  done
)
```

I use parentheses to create a subshell so I don't alter the IFS variable in the current shell.

Comment: you don't have to create a subshell. Please use `while IFS=, read line; do ...`. And your `while` is useless!

Comment: `IFS=, read line` does not actually split the line by commas. The `set -- $line` command actually does that, and for that to work, IFS needs to be set *beforehand*.

Comment: +1, but this *will* give wrong results if any list-elements contain spaces or backslashes, and *can* give wrong results if any list-elements contain question-marks or asterisks. Also, FYI, the components of a pipeline are already run in subshells.