# Fetch values from particular file and display swapped values in terminal

Tags: terminal, grep, command-line-interface, fetch

I have a file named `input.txt` which contains students data in  `StudentName|Class|SchoolName` format.

```
Shriii|Fourth|ADCET
Chaitraliii|Fourth|ADCET
Shubhangi|Fourth|ADCET
Prathamesh|Third|RIT
```

I want to display this values in reverse order for particular college. Example:

```
ADCET|Fourth|Shriii
ADCET|Fourth|Chaitraliii
```

I used `grep 'ADCET$' input.txt` which gives output

```
Shriii|Fourth|ADCET
Chaitraliii|Fourth|ADCET
```

But I want it in reverse order. I also used `grep 'ADCET$' input.txt | sort -r` but didn't get required output

[Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967776/swap-two-columns-awk-sed-python-perl)

Comment: Maybe see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13367179/1970049 for a function to reverse comma-separeted values (you can customize your separator via regexp).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `grep 'ADCET$' input.txt | tac` swapped it vertically. That's not the expected output.

Comment: @dth The input.txt file contains `|` separated values and not `,` separated values.

Comment: `| sed 's/^\([^|]*\)\(|.*|\)\([^|]*\)$/\3\2\1/'`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It worked. Can you give detailed explanation so that I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Added all the explanations to the answer, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use either of the following `sed` or `awk` solutions:

```
grep 'ADCET$' input.txt | sed 's/^\([^|]*\)\(|.*|\)\([^|]*\)$/\3\2\1/'
grep 'ADCET$' input.txt | awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="|"} {temp=$NF;$NF=$1;$1=temp;}1'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/SiVmlh)

**`awk` details**

- `BEGIN {OFS=FS="|"}` - the field separator is set to `|` and the same char will be used for output
- `{temp=$NF;$NF=$1;$1=temp;}1`:

  - `temp=$NF;` - the last field value is assigned to a `temp` variable
  - `$NF=$1;` - the last field is set to Field 1 value
  - `$1=temp;` - the value of Field 1 is set to `temp`
- `1` - makes the `awk` write the output.

**`sed` details**

- `^` - start of the line
- `\([^|]*\)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than `|`
- `\(|.*|\)` - Capturing group 2: `|`, then any 0+ chars and then a `|`
- `\([^|]*\) - Capturing group 3: any 0+ chars other than`|`
- `$` - end of line.

The `\3\2\1` are placeholders for values captured into Groups 1, 2 and 3.